# Sort table by class in TH

Tags: javascript, css, datatables, html-table

I have a table with 10 columns, every column has a different class, for example the last has: `data-tot`

How to sort the table by this class and in descending order?

A full [jsFiddle is available here](https://jsfiddle.net/g1x3egj0/), but a small sample of the HTML looks like this (the `odd` and `even` rows continue for the full data).

```
<table class="sp-league-table sp-data-table sp-sortable-table sp-scrollable-table sp-paginated-table dataTable no-footer" data-sp-rows="30" id="DataTables_Table_9" role="grid">
  <thead>
    <tr role="row">
      <th class="data-rank sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Pos">Pos</th>
      <th class="data-name sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Squadra">Squadra</th>
      <th class="data-gia sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="GIA">GIA</th>
      <th class="data-ros sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="ROS">ROS</th>
      <th class="data-gio sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="6GIO">6GIO</th>
      <th class="data-giotwo sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="5GIO">5GIO</th>
      <th class="data-giothree sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="4GIO">4GIO</th>
      <th class="data-giofour sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="3GIO">3GIO</th>
      <th class="data-tav sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="TAV">TAV</th>
      <th class="data-tot sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_9" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="TOT">TOT</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
      <td class="data-rank">1</td>
      <td class="data-name"><a href="http://www.quartuleague.com/squadra/consulenza-impresa/">CONSULENZA IMPRESA</a></td>
      <td class="data-gia">0.5</td>
      <td class="data-ros">0</td>
      <td class="data-gio">0.5</td>
      <td class="data-giotwo">1</td>
      <td class="data-giothree">0</td>
      <td class="data-giofour">0</td>
      <td class="data-tav">0</td>
      <td class="data-tot">2.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" role="row">
      <td class="data-rank">2</td>
      <td class="data-name"><a href="http://www.quartuleague.com/squadra/new-team/">NEW TEAM</a></td>
      <td class="data-gia">0.5</td>
      <td class="data-ros">2</td>
      <td class="data-gio">1.0</td>
      <td class="data-giotwo">1</td>
      <td class="data-giothree">0</td>
      <td class="data-giofour">0</td>
      <td class="data-tav">0</td>
      <td class="data-tot">4.5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Use the code below to sort table by column specified by jQuery selector `.data-tot` in descending order.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable().column('.data-tot').order('desc').draw();
```

See [`columns().order()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.order%28%29) for more details.

> **DEMO**

See [updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1x3egj0/6/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: sorry not good, i don't want search field, i must show all teams without pagination

Comment: can i use .mytable class instead of #id?

Comment: @barabba58, although this is unrelated to your question but I removed pagination, searching and info controls. You can use class instead if ID if you want.

Comment: @barabba58, you need to include JS/CSS files for DataTables to work, see links under **External resources** in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1x3egj0/6/). See [Installation](http://datatables.net/manual/installation) for more information.

Comment: @barabba58, it works in the fiddle I posted. Can you provide a link to your page where it doesn't work?

Comment: no, is DataTables_Table_9, you can see in the "Fair Play" Tab

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to chat :(

Comment: Somewhere in your code `$.noConflict()` is being run that makes `$` unavailable. Use `jQuery` instead of `$` as a workaround. Also ID `DataTables_Table_9` id doesn't exist when you run your DataTables initialization. Try to use different selector `.sp-template-league-table table` to target specific table. The following code works in the console: `jQuery('.sp-template-league-table table').DataTable().column('.data-tot').order('asc').draw();`

Comment: now i have this error :\

DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable.

Comment: @barabba58, this is because you initialize it more than once. I have used table initialization code in the answer as an example only. If you have initialized your table somewhere else, use only second line in my solution.

Comment: now i'm using this in footer


<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('.sp-template-league-table table').DataTable().column('.data-tot').order('asc').draw();

  </script>

Comment: @barabba58, it's hard to tell without seeing the page, it was a mess when I looked at it. Most-likely you're running the code inline before table is initialized. Now that the answer is unaccepted, not sure how can I help you more.

Comment: @barabba58, You should use this code instead `$(document).ready(function(){ jQuery('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable({ paging: false, searching: false, info: false  }); jQuery('#DataTables_Table_0').DataTable().column('.data-tot').order('asc').draw();  }`

Comment: @barabba58, As an alternative you can use HTML5 `data-` attributes on the table to specify ordering for each table in HTML as shown in [HTML5 data-* attributes](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html) example.

Comment: @barabba58, then use some common class for all your tables with `.data-tot` column instead of '#DataTables_Table_0'

Answer (score 0):

As from you link you are *not* using `DataTables`. you need to simple give an `id` to you table. And the rest will do `DataTables`.
[**Here is updated link**](https://jsfiddle.net/g1x3egj0/2/)

Comment: i need to keep this css style so.. i need only order by TOT column

Comment: do you need to use `DtaTables`??

Comment: no, anything that can make me sort the table "ASC" by "TOT"