# Sort table by a column with DataTables

Tags: javascript, wordpress, datatables

I'm trying to sort a table by a particular column with DataTables, but I receive this warning:

> DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

I put these scripts but maybe I'm doing something wrong:

```
jQuery('.sp-template-league-table table').DataTable({ paging: false, searching: false, info: false, retrieve: true });

jQuery('.sp-template-league-table table').DataTable().column('.data-tot').order('asc').draw();
```

You can see the table in this page: http://www.quartuleague.com/goldcup-2015-girone-gold/

under the "Fair Play" Tab, i want to sort table by "TOT"

Comment: As far as I can see the table actually holds the unique class `.sp-league-table` so `jQuery('.sp-league-table table').DataTable().column('.data-tot').order('asc').draw();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort table by class in TH](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822902/sort-table-by-class-in-th)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the data by default you can also pass along additional parameters on the initialization instead of using `.draw()`:

**Example:** Ascending sorting of the 4th column (indices start at 0)

```
$('#example_table').DataTable( {
    "order": [[ 3, "asc" ]]
} );
```

In your case you need to add the column number of your `data-tot` column (8 or -1) like so:

```
jQuery('.sp-template-league-table table').DataTable({ 
order: [[ 8, "asc" ]],
paging: false, 
searching: false, 
info: false, 
retrieve: true 
});
```

Comment: It is the opposite : It is **your** example that will cause errors - `jQuery('.sp-template-league-table table').DataTable().xxx()` can be done a million times without errors...

Comment: Whats wrong with my example? Have a look at the docs https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

Comment: proof of concept -> **http://jsfiddle.net/s2fj7wu5/** yes, the docs describe the first initialisation, that will fail if you repeat it. `jQuery('.sp-template-league-table table').DataTable()` works well. Or perhaps I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: I suggested to do the sorting using initialization arguments instead of using `.draw()`. Clearly, you should not call the plugin multiple times. I'll edit my answer so this point is more clear.